# Data transformation on PCA scores

Tags: r, pca, heteroscedasticity, generalized-additive-model

I have 40 predictors on which I ran a PCA and shortlisted 14 PCs (explaining 95%) as my predictors.

I am running a generalised additive model with 14 PCs as predictors. I check the model assumption of GAM which shows that my data violates the assumption of homogeneity.

My question is this:

(1) Can I do a data transformation of PCs scores so that my model does not violate the homogeneity assumption. I am confused because I have already done a YeoJohnson transformation on my actual data and scaled them before doing a PCA. Does it make sense to do another transformation on the PCA scores itself?

(2) Homogeneity violation shows that my variance increases with increasing response value. How can I improve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

(1) If you do a new transformation upon already transformed data, how do you want to interpret the estimated coefficients? Maybe OK if you only needs predictions, but I think best to avoid. Try to find some more direct solution. A YeoJohnsen transformation (like Box-Cox on predictors) seems to me to be old technology, maybe it is better to look into using splines. 
(2)  Did you transform the response in any way? You didn't tell us. To answer (2) meaningfully we really need more context. What does the variables in the model represent? What is the goal of the analysis?